# remote desktop crashes when browse visual studio projects

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, webserver, localhost, visual-studio

so I am working on a remote desktop, which is for a remote server(this server is hosting the online version of the web app that I am developing, but I am developing a local copy,also stored on that remote server); the remote desktop is running Windows Server 2012R2; I can develop fine in visual studio, but when I click IE or Firefox, etc, in Visual Studio, to browse my project in a browser,

the browser try to open localhost, then before anything load on browser screen, the remote desktop will crash and say "the connection has been lost". But is it really about the network connection? I don't know. I can reopen the remote desktop, but I can't browse my VS project anyway.

comparing to that, if I create a remote desktop on a local server and use visual studio there, nothing goes wrong. So what could be changed to that remote server configurations to fix this problem, if I have to work on a remote desktop for that remote server? Or why things go wrong anyway?

I am not familiar with remote desktops at all, so I don't know whether it is a dumb question (0.0) But I don't find any solutions online to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing the port assignment conflict. Make sure that your web application and  Remote Desktop service are not using the same TCP port. The default port assigned to RDP is 3389.

Comment: thank you so much! I am not quite sure about whether I understand your answer fully, but your answer seems to be relevant to my problem. I will update this page later to report whether I solve the problem.